# How to use Google Cloud Speech v1 on Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, google-cloud-speech

I recently updated my Android Google Cloud Speech code from v1beta1 to v1. There were a couple of changes in the API, one of them was a new method called getWordsList().

I want to use the getWordsList() in my Android project, however the method doesn't seem to be visible to my code:

```
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechGrpc;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechRecognitionAlternative;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeResponse;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.WordInfo;

...

public void onNext(StreamingRecognizeResponse response) {
  int numOfResults = response.getResultsCount();
  if( numOfResults > 0 ){
    for (int i=0;i<numOfResults;i++){
      StreamingRecognitionResult result = response.getResultsList().get(i);
      SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
      for (WordInfo wordInfo: alternative.getWordsList()) { //-->>Cannot resolve 'method'
        System.out.println(wordInfo.getWord());
        System.out.println(wordInfo.getStartTime().getSeconds() + " ");
      }
      ...
```

This code is from the official [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/speech/Recognize.java), however, I am getting the following error:

> Cannot resolve method 'getWordsList()'

Here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.0.0'
        }
        javalite {
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each {
            task ->
                task.builtins {
                    remove javanano
                    java {
                    }
                }
                task.plugins {
                    grpc {
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '25.0.0'
    grpcVersion = '1.4.0'
}

dependencies {
    // Generic dependencies
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:0.23.1-alpha'

    // Support libraries
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    // gRPC
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${grpcVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
    }
    compile("io.grpc:grpc-stub:${grpcVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
    }
    compile("io.grpc:grpc-auth:${grpcVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
    }
    compile("io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:${grpcVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
    }
    // OAuth2 for Google API
    compile('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.3.0') {
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }

}
```

I also noticed, I cannot use all grpc libraries, for example the following library cannot be imported:

```
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.StreamingCallable;
```

How can I use getWordsList() correctly in Android? Am I not using the correct build version?

Comment: There is unfortunately no correct build version for you to be using at this time. Google Cloud Java client libraries [do not currently support Android](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java). That is to say that there might be ways to get the libraries to work but since they're not officially supported it is expected that not all functionality would be there.

Answer (score 0):

I use this instead of getWordList():

```
final SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternatives(0);
text = alternative.getTranscript();
```

Hope it works.

Comment: this doesn't provide metadata that getWordsList is supposed to provide.

Answer (score 0):

You did not enclosed the code you use for the request, but make sure you are adding setEnableWordTimeOffsets to the RecognizeRequest :

```
  public void recognizeInputStream(InputStream stream) {
    try {
        mApi.recognize(
                RecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setConfig(RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                                .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                                .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                                .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                                .setEnableWordTimeOffsets(true)
                                .build())
                        .setAudio(RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
                                .setContent(ByteString.readFrom(stream))
                                .build())
                        .build(),
                mFileResponseObserver);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading the input", e);
    }
}
```